# Safe way to get "rm dir -rf" working (place options after dir name like on linux)

Tags: bash

I don't know how many times I've done it. I'll type in `rm dir` and then have to move the cursor back and add in `-rf` to the command. Probably 10,000.

In linux, I can just add the options in after the dir name.

Is there any good bash magic that will let this safely happen? Here is a non-functional prototype of a simple bash `rm` function that I think would do the trick:

```
function rm() {
  if $2 eq "-rf" then run "builtin rm $2 $1"
}
```

But before I reinvent the wheel, I wanted to see if there were other options I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: `myrm foo bar -rf`, so your function might need some more logic :-)

Comment: `if $2 eq "-rf" then run "builtin rm $2 $1"` is not a valid `if` _statement_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the GNU version of `rm` with `brew install coreutils`. It will install into `/usr/local/bin/grm` to avoid conflicts with the standard version. But you can easily overcome this by aliasing it to `rm` for interactive shells.